# Sort Grid Columns by "column_order" in JQWidgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqxwidgets

Is that possible to sort grid columns by `column order` dynamically using `JQWidgets(v2.8.2)`?

Comment: Please elaborate & provide your current code. As it currently stands, this would not be considered a quality question.

Comment: I am generating a grid by `$(gridId).jqxGrid({source: dataAdapter,......,columns: colData.columns});`The default column properties come from database, which is initialized from a json file.Now, on "personalize grid" option of this grid, I should be able to change the order of columns(which is done). But the new column order doesn't take effect after refreshing it by `$(gridId).jqxGrid('refresh');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before generating the grid by

```
    `$(gridId).jqxGrid({
        source: dataAdapter,
        .............,
        ............,
        ............,
        columns:colData.columns  //column property from database
    });`
```

I sorted the the columns by `columnOrder` with `sortColumnByOrder(colData.columns, 'columnOrder');` The original method is like below

```
function sortColumnByOrder(array, key) {
return array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var x = a[key];
    var y = b[key];
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
});
}
```

And its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "sortby" method.

```
 $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('sortby', 'firstname', 'asc');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/7yWdu/. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think there is difference between `column property` and `column value(cell value)`. The `column order` is a column property. `$('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('sortby', 'firstname', 'asc');` This is for row sorting by `'firstname'` column values within this column i guess.

Comment: the column order is "asc". It could be "desc" or null.